# How to get the index of a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following code from the designer:

```
<table class="items">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="name">name</th>
        <th id="category">category</th>
        <th id="zip">zip</th>
        <th id="city">city</th>
        <th id="street">street</th>
        <th id="latitude">latitude</th>
        <th id="longitude">longitude</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>MyCompany</td>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>18360</td>
            <td>Stroudsburg</td>
            <td>4 Scott Str.</td>
            <td>40.9891</td>
            <td>-75.1962</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jQuery, how can I get the longitude and latitude values by taking into account the `th` elements with the specified `id`? The order of the columns might change later so direct indexing is not an option. However the `id` values will remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var latIndex = $("#latitude").index(),
    longIndex = $("#longitude").index();

// do something with the values from each row
$("tbody tr").each(function() {
   var $tds = $(this).find("td"),
       latValue = $tds.eq(latIndex).text(),
       longValue = $tds.eq(longIndex).text();

    console.log(latValue + ", " + longValue);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaVp/

Comment: I accept this solution due to the single `var` declaration, the jsfiddle demo and using `text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 3):

```
var latIndex = document.getElementById('latitude').cellIndex;
var longIndex = document.getElementById('longitude').cellIndex;
var row = document.querySelector(".items .odd");
var latitude = row.cells[latIndex];
var longiture = row.cells[longIndex];
latitude = latitude.textContent || latitude.innerText;
longitude = longitude.textContent || longitude.innerText;
```

Using ONLY raw JavaScript, guaranteed to be at least 8 times faster than jQuery (20 on more complex pages) ;)

Comment: Knew I was forgetting something. Of course, if the HTML is flawless then those two are synonymous here, but `cells` is "more correct".

Comment: Thank you. People need to understand that since JS is already a high-level language, making an even higher one with it (namely, jQuery), is dangerously slow... Granted it may be more convenient to write `$('#someid')` instead of `document.getElementById('someid')`, but is it really worth processing hundreds of commands just to get one element?

Comment: No `querySelector()` support in IE6 or IE7.  So, it depends upon what browsers you want to support.  I use plain javascript when max speed is needed or when it does the job just as well, but much of the time, I save both code writing time and bugs by using a proven cross-browser library.  98% of the time (like in this case), the speed difference is irrelevant, but the cross browser support is a real time saver and bug saver.

Comment: That is true, I will admit. However if IE6 or 7 are to be accomodated for then IDs should be used more liberally (or even `name` attributes for the `getElementsByName` function). In this case, setting an ID on the table (eg. #mytable) and using `document.getElementById('mytable').tBodies[0].rows[0].cells` would work just fine.

Comment: +1 for `cellIndex`. +1 for no silly abstraction layer. -1 for `querySelector` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.index()` method to get the location of the latitude and longitude headers and then get that same location in the body.

```
// get column number for lat and long
var latIndex = $("#latitude").index();
var longIndex = $("#longitude").index(); 

// get rows that contain the actual data
var rows = $(".items .odd td");

// get the desired data from the same columns as titles
var latitude = rows.eq(latIndex).text();
var longitude = rows.eq(longIndex).text();
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bCXbw/

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
var lat = jQuery("#latitude");
var lng = jQuery("#longitude");

var latInd = jQuery("table thead th").index( lat ) + 1;
var lngInd = jQuery("table thead th").index( lng ) + 1;

var lats = jQuery("table tbody tr td:nth-child(" + latInd + ")");
var lngs = jQuery("table tbody tr td:nth-child(" + lngInd  + ")");

console.log(lats);
console.log(lngs);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZznU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lat = $('#latitude').index();
var long = $('#longitude').index();
console.log($('tr.odd td:eq('+lat+')').html()); //outputs 40.9891
console.log($('tr.odd td:eq('+long+')').html()) // outputs -75.1962
```

This assumes that the ordering of element is consistent, which looking at your code it should be.